# Convert float to CharSequence

Tags: android, java

Имеются элементы EditText и TextView.

```
private EditText mEdit;
private TextView mText;
private float mTextSize=20;
```

Через кнопки меняю размер в EditText.

```
        ...
        case R.id.button_plus:
            if (mTextSize <=72)
                mTextSize+=2;
            mEdit.setTextSize(mTextSize);
            break;
        case R.id.button_minus:
            if (mTextSize>=20)
                mTextSize-=2;
            mEdit.setTextSize(mTextSize);
            break;
        ...
```

Как отобразить значение текущего размера шрифта в текстовом поле (mText)? Методу setText требуется тип CharSequence, а у меня float (переменная mTextSize).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотря какой формат вам нужен. Но если просто втупую, то можно

```
Float.toString(mTextSize);
```

PS: String является частным случаем CharSequence